# Scraping HTML and manipulate elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to GET html from my second site(subdomain) and use it to build a part of this site.

**HTML site:**

```
<head>
<body>

<div id = "items">
  <div id = "#one">
    <ul>
       <li><a href = "#">Click here</a></li>
       <li><img src = "/images.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id = "#two">
    <ul>
       <li><a href = "#">Click here</a></li>
       <li><img src = "/images2.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</head>
```

I want to do things like counting number of div elements, getting list etc.

**This is what I tried:**

```
$.ajax({ 
 url: '/mysite/items.html', 
success: function(data) { 
  //Need to manipulate here

  var html = $(data);

  var items = $.get(".items", html);
  var numItems = $('.items').length;

  console.log(data); //There is data(Whole HTML is here.)

  console.log(items); //This is undefined??
  console.log(numItems): //This is undefined??

  var raw = html.get(".offers"); //Complains doesnot have a get method??

},
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see what you want os

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mysite/items.html',
    success: function (data) {
        //Need to manipulate here

        var $html = $(data);

        //use .find() to find elements with class items in data
        var $items = $html.find('.items');
        //use the items object to get the length
        var numItems = $items.length;

        console.log(data);

        console.log($items);
        console.log(numItems):

        //need to use .find() to get the elements matching a selector
        var raw = $htm.find(".offers");

    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't load a non-javascript file from another domain because of the same-origin security policy. If you own both sites you can enable [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/)

Otherwise You'll need a server-side language to act as a proxy

Comment: Hi I am loading this file from my subdomain. I can get HTML file just fine. The problem is with manipulating, getting elements and breaking them. Thanks

Comment: Javascript has no default way of parsing DOM documents like xml/html. You'll need to find a library for it, like jquery

Comment: @helion3 he is using jQuery at the moment it seems.

Comment: I see, he added the jquery code to the question. Nice